# How can I change an array value with a click?

Tags: php, html, arrays, ajax

I've seen references to Ajax for this, but I'm not entirely sure how I could integrate that with the arrays and still have a functioning system. I want to change the value of $place and $title each time a user presses the button, and I know that I'll need an if statement and some way of processing a form (no clicks in PHP), but I don't know anything else beyond that. I've pasted my PHP and the HTML button below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>StatsCalc V1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sheen.css">
<link rel="script" type="text/javascript" href="slide.js">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
      <?php
        $place = 0;
        $title = 0;

        echo '<div class="boxes"><h1>Statistics Calculator: Version 1</h1></div>';

        $links = array('<div class="fancyBoxes"><a href="standardisedForm.php"><img class="mainPic" src="normalDist.svg" alt="a normal distribution, courtesy openclipart.org"></a></div>', "", "");
        echo $links[$place];

        /*if($_GET){
            if(isset($_GET['clickies'])){
                $place = 1;
                $title = 1;
            }
        }*/

        if($_POST['clickies'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
            $place = 1;
            $title = 1;
        }

        $subtitle = array('<div class="boxes"><h1>Standardised Score</h1></div>', '<div class="boxes"><h1>Standard Deviation</h1></div>', '<div class="boxes"><h1>Averages</h1></div>');
        echo $subtitle[$title];

      ?>
      <input type="submit" id="clickies" name="clickies" value="" />
      <script src="move.js"></script>
      <script src="slide.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
      <!--The calculator must be able to field standardised score, standard deviation, and averages (mean/median/mode)-->
      <!--Headings will be assigned with an array; slides will be navigated with tabs on either side of the window-->
      <!--Credit to https://openclipart.org/detail/171055/normal-distn-shaded-outside-1s-by-oderwald-171055 for the Standardised Score image/label thingy-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your full HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this could give you idea on how to do it.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

      if (isset($_POST['clickies'])) {
         $count = intval($_POST['count']);
         $count++;
         $place = $count;
         $title = $count;
      }

   } else {
      $place = 0;
      $title = 0;
   }

        echo '<div class="boxes"><h1>Statistics Calculator: Version 1</h1></div>';

        $links = array('<div class="fancyBoxes"><a href="standardisedForm.php"><img class="mainPic" src="normalDist.svg" alt="a normal distribution, courtesy openclipart.org"></a></div>', "", "");

        echo $links[$place];

        echo $place; echo "<br/>";

        $subtitle = array('<div class="boxes"><h1>Standardised Score</h1></div>', '<div class="boxes"><h1>Standard Deviation</h1></div>', '<div class="boxes"><h1>Averages</h1></div>');

        echo $subtitle[$title];

?>
   <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="submit" id="clickies" name="clickies" value="" />
      <input type="hidden" id="count" name="count" value="<?php echo $place;?>" />   
   </form>
```

what I did is need to put the button inside a form and put a method= post
and make it submit it to the same page

i also store the count in a hidden input and pass it always when the form is submitted and update its value on the form,

try to modify according to your need

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful and can be easily modified :D

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $_SESSION["place"] = 0;
    $place = 0;
    $title = 0;
    session_start();
    echo '<div class="boxes"><h1>Statistics Calculator: Version 1</h1></div>';

    $links = array('<div class="fancyBoxes"><a href="standardisedForm.php"><img     class="mainPic" src="normalDist.svg" alt="a normal distribution, courtesy openclipart.org">    </a></div>', "", "");

    if($_POST['clickies'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        $_SESSION["place"] =  $_SESSION["place"] + 1;
        $title = 1;
    }
    echo $links[$_SESSION["place"]];
    $subtitle = array('<div class="boxes"><h1>Standardised Score</h1></div>', '<div     class="boxes"><h1>Standard Deviation</h1></div>', '<div class="boxes"><h1>Averages</h1></div>');

    echo $subtitle[$title];
 ?>
<form method="post" action="">
      <input type="submit" id="clickies" name="clickies" value="submit" />
</form>
```

you can use session of php.